how to write @GOTPCREL in go assembly
I'm trying to write an instruction that loads the address of an external symbol in go assembly.
In normal x86_64 assembly, the instruction I want is:
cmpq    $0, _clock_gettime@GOTPCREL(%rip)

This loads the address of _clock_gettime from the global offset table and compares it to zero.
How do you do this in go assembly?

In Go, you should be able to just write CMPQ $clock_gettime(SB), $0.  Does that work for you?

no, that gives me the address of the function stub in __TEXT __symbol_stub1, I want to read the function pointer in __DATA __nl_symbol_ptr

Add some context, it should be easy to make a [mcve]. Go doesn't use dynamic linking by default. Also, you are on macOS on AppleSilicon, which should use the _got section and not the __nl_symbol_ptr AFAIK. If your function is not bound yet, the lazy pointer will point to the stub. Again, a [mcve] should remove any doubt and allow people with macOS answer you.

I'm not sure what you think a minimal reproducible example would look like.   This isn't a question about why go is doing something, like printing a particular error message.   It's a question about how to get it to do something.   The example is the instruction above.  I want an input I can type into my source that will output that instruction in the resulting binary.
I'm testing with go1.21.9 on Mac OS 14.5, on arm64.   The binaries go produces do dynamically link to libSystem, and the GOT section is called __nl_symbol_ptr.

FWIW I'm pretty sure the correct answer is, there is no way to do this in go assembly without modifying the assembler and linker.
